# How to specify a data Source in Rally API

Tags: javascript, rally

Can I specify my param when declaring a datasource?

var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('2004571051',
                                                    '5022032422',
                                                    'false',
                                                    'true');

Where **WORKSPACE_OID** =2004571051
**PROJECT_OID** =5022032422

**PROJECT_SCOPING_UP** = false
**PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN** =false

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right on. That should work like a charm.

I copied this out of the [docs](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rally-data-source) for a reference:

```
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my attempt did not return anything.. I'm not sure why .The Workspace and Project Id are correct though.

Comment: Did you open up the debugger and see if the server responded with anything?

Comment: I'm using a text pad so I'm not sure about the debugger . I tried F12 in IE and could not find any relevant information.

Comment: You may have some challenges developing Apps in IE. Their developer toolkit could use some love. Would it be possible for you to use Chrome to debug with? As a side note what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE9. I'll try with chrome